# shell script - How can i make multiple-read?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I can not give much explanation because my English is bad. The example of what I want to do is below;

try.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "Enter the port:"
read ports
if [ ! -d "$ports" ]; then

mkdir -p /root/port$ports
echo "The folder was created for $ports"
wget -q www.example.com/example.tar.bz2
tar -xjf example.tar.bz2
su root -c "screen -A -m -d -S 'example$ports' ./example -RunningAsRootIsEvilAndIKnowThat"
echo "$ports started."
else
exit 0
fi
```

Putty;

```
root@ubuntu:~# sh try.sh
Enter the port: 4445, 4546
Created folder 'port4445'
Created folder 'port4546'
4445 started.
4546 started.
```

How can i make?

Comment: And what have you tried in shell script?

Comment: Nothing. I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Why do you use `,` as the delimiter? I would simply use space

Comment: It will be in SPACE, it will not matter. I just gave an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=, read -p "Enter the Hosts: " -ra hosts </dev/tty
IFS=, read -p "Enter the Port: " -ra ports </dev/tty

for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
    for port in "${ports[@]}"; do
        nc -vz $host $port
    done
done
```

Runtime:

```
bash try.sh
Enter the Port: 80
Enter the Hosts: 127.0.0.1
localhost [127.0.0.1] 80 (http) open
```

`nc -vz $host $port` will check if the `$host` is listening on `$port`

`IFS=,` splits input, In our case with `,` Think of it as input separator.

`-p` To display message.

`-a` puts input into array

Comment: Changing the script to expect whitespace-separated tokens instead of comma-separated tokens would simplify the logic and integrate better with other tools.

Comment: Sure, Just change the IFS. The example provided by OP has `,`

Answer (score -2):

use $* to read arguments:

```
 echo $* | awk '{ i=1; while(i<=NF) { print $i; i++; } }'
```

or

```
 for i in $*; do
   echo $i 
 done
```

Comment: I do not want for Bash. I need it for Shell script

Comment: This works in generic `sh` but it seems to be the answer to a different (though tangentially related) question. I think it's trying to say "don't read input interactively in the first place; make your script accept the port numbers as command-line arguments instead, and both you and we will be happier".

Comment: Downvote for the lack of quoting and the silly Awk workaround for no obvious benefit.  The proper way is to use `"$@"` (yes, with the double quotes) instead of `$*` and to quote `"$i"` inside the loop.

Comment: This script works for me. it is not compulsory to include double quotes